# xcode 4.2 keeps crashing with internal error

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, xcode4.2

I am new to Mac development. I have Lion and installed Xcode 4.2. However, I keep getting a crash whenever I try to click on any of the .m files. I just created a new project and as soon as I selected the folder that contains the .h and .m files, it gives me a crash with internal error. I uninstalled once and reinstalled it completely. Still the same issue.
I am basically a Windows developer ( .NET ). I am trying to learn iOS App development.
This is the error from the crash dialog that pops up:

Internal Error
Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "Continue" to continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state.  Choose "Crash" to halt Xcode and file a bug with Crash Reporter. Choosing "Crash" will result in the loss of all unsaved data.

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]:

    attempt to insert nil value (key: SourceTree(Dev))
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff9116926a __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff94a3dd5e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff911690ba +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff91169044 +[NSException raise:format:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff9112629b -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:] (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x000000010930b5c8 -[Xcode3Group resolutionContextForStrategies:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x0000000105ee6785 -[IDEGroupIdentityAndType _resolutionContextForContentWithStrategies:] (in IDEKit)
  7  0x0000000105ee6e24 -[IDEGroupIdentityAndType customResolutionStrategiesDisplayNamePopupItems] (in IDEKit)
  8  0x00007fff897be434 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter (in Foundation)
  9  0x00007fff897be3e9 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] (in Foundation)
 10  0x00007fff897dde76 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] (in Foundation)
 11  0x0000000105e3a735 -[IDEInspectorTextEnumerationProperty rebuildMenuContent] (in IDEKit)
 12  0x000000010561e028 -[DVTDelayedValidator doValidation:] (in DVTKit)
 13  0x0000000105e3b14c -[IDEInspectorTextEnumerationProperty configureEnumeratedOptions] (in IDEKit)
 14  0x0000000105e3b69e -[IDEInspectorTextEnumerationProperty bindAndConfigure] (in IDEKit)
 15  0x0000000105e361c9 -[IDEInspectorProperty viewDidInstall] (in IDEKit)
 16  0x00007fff911602e1 -[NSObject performSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
 17  0x00007fff91164722 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] (in CoreFoundation)
 18  0x0000000105eefe8d -[IDEInspectorPropertyContainingView propertiesDidInstall] (in IDEKit)
 19  0x0000000105eeffcf -[IDEInspectorPropertyContainingView viewDidMoveToWindow] (in IDEKit)
 20  0x00007fff8fdf1153 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 21  0x00007fff8fd1d124 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
 22  0x00007fff910f7314 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 23  0x00007fff8fdf10d7 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 24  0x00007fff8fd1d124 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
 25  0x00007fff910f7314 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 26  0x00007fff8fdf10d7 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 27  0x00007fff8fd1d124 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
 28  0x00007fff910f7314 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 29  0x00007fff8fdf10d7 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 30  0x00007fff8fd1d124 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
 31  0x00007fff910f7314 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 32  0x00007fff8fdf10d7 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 33  0x00007fff8fd1d124 __NSViewRecursionHelper (in AppKit)
 34  0x00007fff910f7314 CFArrayApplyFunction (in CoreFoundation)
 35  0x00007fff8fdf10d7 -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 36  0x00007fff8fdef3e2 -[NSView addSubview:] (in AppKit)
 37  0x00000001088fe5b4 -[NSView(IBAppKitViewIntegration) ibSwizzledNSViewDebug_addSubview:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 38  0x000000010569667d -[DVTDisclosureView layoutTopDown] (in DVTKit)
 39  0x000000010560e1c3 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
 40  0x000000010560e272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
 41  0x000000010560e272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
 42  0x000000010560e272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
 43  0x000000010560e272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
 44  0x000000010560e272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
 45  0x000000010560e272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
 46  0x000000010560e272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
 47  0x000000010560e272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
 48  0x000000010560e272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
 49  0x000000010560e272 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
 50  0x000000010560e037 +[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:] (in DVTKit)
 51  0x000000010560dde1 -[DVTAutoLayoutView viewWillDraw] (in DVTKit)
 52  0x00007fff8fd1bc11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 53  0x00007fff8fd1bc11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 54  0x00007fff8fd1bc11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 55  0x00007fff8fd1bc11 -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 56  0x00007fff8fd1a952 -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:suppressRecursion:] (in AppKit)
 57  0x00007fff8fd196c1 -[NSView displayIfNeeded] (in AppKit)
 58  0x00007fff8fd1907d _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints (in AppKit)
 59  0x00007fff91128f37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 60  0x00007fff91128e96 __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
 61  0x00007fff910fe159 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 62  0x00007fff910fdae6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 63  0x00007fff8d3753d3 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 64  0x00007fff8d37c58f ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 65  0x00007fff8d37c4ca BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
 66  0x00007fff8fcdd3f1 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 67  0x00007fff8fcdccf5 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 68  0x00007fff8fcd962d -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 69  0x00007fff8ff5880c NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 70  0x00000001053e7eec (in Xcode)
```

Comment: Try posting this on Apple's developer forums as well. http://devforums.apple.com

Comment: @JoePasq, that was the first thing I tried to do. Unfortunately, they wanted me to be a paid member first. I want to first learn to develop on Mac and then may be i will shell out the $99 to become a paid member. So for now SO is my savior

Comment: Okay, I should have noted that. I wouldn't pay $100 just for forum access unless you plan on releasing an app through the store anyway.

Comment: @JoePasq I just checked the apple dev forms... there are quite a few posts about essentially this exact error.  O_O  I assure you Apple knows it exits.

Answer (score 2):

This definitely sounds like a bug in Xcode, and not anything you're responsible for.

Do you have exactly Xcode 4.2? The current release of Xcode is 4.2.1, and it may (or may not) contain a fix for this issue.

If you're using 4.2.1 already, or the latest version continues to exhibit this behavior, please let Apple know by submitting a bug report to their issue tracking service:

[Link to Apple Radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn)

Comment: craig, i downloaded it from Appstore.It's 4.2.1 and that's the version available from Appstore. Researching a little bit, I was able to find 4.2 and am now downloading it. I will uninstall the 4.2.1 and install 4.2 and see if that helps.

Comment: I can attest from personal experience that 4.2 is unstable as well.  You should be able to click "Continue" in the dialog that pops up, just be aware that strange behavior *MAY* follow. (I haven't seen any personally)  Things will improve as Apple gets more of a handle on the bugs, but there's not much we devs can do for now except wait for bug fixes.

Comment: @SplinterReality good to know. now i dont have to waste my time installing 4.2 and will continue with 4.2.1 that i currently have. it's annoying though. can i actually install any other xcode version like a 4.0 or 3.x that's more stable but still works on Lion and the latest iOS i.e iOS 5?

Comment: Unfortunately 4.2 is the version that's built for iOS 5.  You can use prior versions to build your app, but be aware that features like Storyboards (Really quite useful for a form based application, games, not so much) will be unavailable.  You may also get rejected by Apple when you submit the app if you're not using the latest Xcode, but I emphasize *MAY*.  They really do like you to keep things updated as much as possible, and I've seen reminders to "compile against the latest APIs" with the expressed threat that not doing so may cause app rejection.